# Get back only one file from folder which is deleted in svn

Tags: svn, version-control

In our project we have a release branch and devloper branch. At start of release every developer gets copy of release branch into it's personal branch and start working.

tree is like this

branches->releases->release1
                    release2
                    release3->release
                            ->dev
                                 ->developer1
                                 ->developer2

I made some mistake and have to start from scratch. So instead of reverting back, I remove my developer branch and recreated a branch (basically folder branches/releases/release3/developer). I then copied branches/releases/release3/release to this folder and start working.

Now I want back some of the files from deleted folder. Is there a way to do that? I just want specific files from particular revision.

I tried looking in to svn log and then checking out branches/releases/release3 folder for that particular revision but it is very big and I do not have enough disk space.

I tried checking out with --depth empty option and then just updating the specific file  I want but that gives me latest version of files.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Read [SVNBook | Resurrecting Deleted Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect).

The following commands should help you restore the file:

1. Checkout a working copy of the repository subtree that contains the file in question: `svn checkout URL`.
2. Copy the file from older revision before deletion into your working copy:

   `svn copy URL-TO-FILE-TO-RECOVER@REVNUM-PRIOR-TO-DELETE PATH-TO-FILE-IN-WC`

NOTE: `svn copy` command copies a file as it was in revision prior to delete by specifying peg revision with '@' sign. The revision number should be of revision prior to the commit where you deleted the file in repository.